# How to define a route which chooses to right Controller on the fly /{slug}

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I am currently facing the challenge, that I have the same route pattern for two Controllers.

To make it easier, let's say we have a `BlogController` and a `PageController`. Both controllers have the same route `/{slug}`.

Of course, in this simple example I could prefix the routes for the `BlogController` with `/blog/{slug}` and have two simple routes then. But this isn't an option in my case. Both Controller's routes should definitely be just `/{slug}` without any pre- / postfixes.

At the moment, I have one route /{slug} which triggers a SlugController. In this Controller I first check, if there is a Blog-record with this slug. If yes, I invoke the `BlogController`. Same check for `PageController`. Otherwise 404.

Is there any smarter way, to do this check, which Controller should be used for a given slug earlier? In the `routes/web.php`?

Comment: Wondering why you cant use `/blog/` as a prefix, that would fix all problems without implementing hacky solutions. If you really want to make it work as described, I would stick with your `SlugController`, however what you could also do is have a single controller `ViewController` or something, and just implement the slug-checking logic there and then call the right controller method to show a view for that specific slug.

Comment: You could also create a helper or blade-directive that checks the slug in the view and already determines what controller it should hit before it even gets to a controller.

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions

1 - You can specify the type in the url

```
website.com/page/slug
website.com/slug
```

2 - You can make one route but controller 2 methods

Depending on the type in the table, if it is blog or page

3 - The third solution, and I think this is what you are looking for and want to hear

You can specify the same route url and call different controllers based on the parameter

```
Route::get('/{slug}', [App\Http\Controllers\PageController::class, 'index'])->where('slug', '(about|contact|any page from pages list)');

Route::get('/{slug}', [App\Http\Controllers\BlogController::class, 'index']);
```

Comment: What what if, I don't know the slugs of Page's when writing the code? (about the when())

Comment: @rakete 
You can use query to fetch pages slug
Names from the database and convert it to an array
and use it